# Can I specify default field aliases in Korma?

Tags: clojure, korma

I have a MySQL field called `thing_id`, but I want to reference it as `:thing-id` in my code. I can define an entity like this:

```
(defentity thing
  (entity-fields :id [:thing_id :thing-id]))
```

so that when I fetch things:

```
(select thing)
```

The MySQL field that contains an underscore is transformed:

```
[{:id 1 :thing-id 2}]
```

But I can't select with the aliased:

```
(select thing (where (= :thing-id 2)))
```

gives

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
Unknown column 'thing.thing-id' in 'where clause'
```

I can fix it in each `where` call:

```
(select thing (where (= :thing_id 2)))
```

But I was hoping that the alias works both way. It doesn't appear to. Is there a way to set an alias that can be used in a `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit too late, but here it goes...

Use a naming strategy, more [here](http://korma.github.io/Korma/korma.config.html#var-set-naming). So your [spec](http://korma.github.io/Korma/korma.db.html#var-defdb) should look like:

```
...
(:require [camel-snake-kebab.core :refer [->kebab-case ->snake_case]])
...

(def db-spec
  {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   :subprotocol "mysql"
   :delimiters "`"
   :unsafe true
   :subname db-subname
   :user db-user
   :password db-password
   :naming {:keys ->kebab-case
            :fields ->snake_case}})
```

Comment: Not too late! Will be useful next time. Thanks very much indeed.